# How do I hide the overflowing part of an element which is behind another element?

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a custom progress bar. Basically I have a `.fill` rectangular container which is behind a `.progress` container which has a transparent background and occupies the same width but has rounded corners.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<p><button onclick="updateProgress()">Click me</button></p>

<div id="profileSetupProg" class="progress">
  <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.progress {
  $height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: $height;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: $height/2;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  
  .fill {
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
progress = 0;

function updateProgress() {
  var prog = document.getElementById("profileSetupProg");
  var fill = prog.querySelector('.fill');
  progress += 5;
  fill.style.width = progress + "%";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `overflow:hidden` be on the parent element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just missed an **overflow** option in the progress class. **progress** class need **overflow:hidden** property. Here the solution to your issues on codepen , it works there properly with overflow. https://codepen.io/salmanaabir/pen/BaQVprZ

```
.progress {
     $height: 50px;
     width: 300px;
     height: $height;
     position: relative;
     background: grey;
     border-radius: $height/2;
     background: none;
     border: 2px solid #000;
     overflow: hidden;

      .fill {
         width: 0%;
         height: 100%;
         position: absolute;
         background-color: lightgreen;
         left: 0px;
         top: 0px;
         z-index: -1;
      }
   }
```